# Ienumerable in debug-time watch question

Tags: c#

When I have an IEnumerable collection and I debug it/use the watch feature, it says "selecting results view will enumerate results set".

Am I right in thinking that if I click the results view, MoveNext() is called and the results enumerated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will call `GetEnumerator()` to create an iterator, and then alternate between calls to `MoveNext()` and `Current` until `MoveNext()` returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will get an enumerator and iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

not iqueryable. sorry.
<strike>Actually, the query is un-deferred and executed. Now your problem is that it cannot be enumerated again. Another case of observation changes an object, eh?</strike>

Comment: What "query" are you talking about? There's no indication this is a LINQ question :)

Comment: thus the strike. i could just delete but am a self hating runner offer of the fingers and wish to be punished for my rash arrogance. thank you sir. may i havanutha?

Comment: but if it was a q about iq i would be right on the money. <goes off to find a question to fit this answer>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Debugger watch feature needs to enumerate it.